# tinyMCE delete text without IMG in paragraph?

Tags: tinymce

Here is what I need to do: For example we have paragraph with some text and also img inserted I need to delete only the text without the IMG, but I dont know how to set that kind of condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do that in jQuery if you got some kind of identifier:

```
$('.container p').html($('.container p img'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8xbEp/  - a fiddle example

But maybe it would be better if you just set the image to be non-editable within tinyMCE, depending on your goals.

**EDIT**

This is an fiddle showing how to use non-editable content inside a contenteditable field (such as tinyMCE)

http://jsfiddle.net/uUKPA/35/

You need to wrap the contenteditable="false" inside another element with contenteditable="false" to be sure it's not removable in all browsers, such as IE.

```
<div contenteditable="false"><img src="img.gif" contentedtitable="false"/></div>
```

Comment: Is there a build in function that tells tinyMCE to not edit the IMG ? Because the IMG is inside the .mceContentBody. And also this is not what I want to achieve. In the Fiddle example there is no text... I want to prevent the IMG deletion when user deletes the text inside the paragraph where the IMG is :)

Comment: In the fiddle, there is text but I remove it with jQuery. You could try wrapping the image in a div with contenteditable=flase, like this `<div contenteditable="false"><img src="img.gif" contentedtitable="false"/></div>`. The extra DIV wrapper is to fix a bug in IE that will allow edits on children but not grandchildren elements.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you Christoffer! THANK YOU!